# String Replacement Within Tags

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, str-replace

This is my string I'm getting from an array field:

```
[email_content] => 

Dear {NAME},

{USR}Thank You For Connecting With "Company" .Your Username is {$username}.{/USR}



{PWD}Thank You For Connecting With "Company".Please Click on the below Link to Resest Yor Password.{/PWD}
 {$password_link}

Thanks & Regards
ABCD Team.
```

Sometimes I want to omit only the {USR} and {/USR} tags of the whole string with null leaving the content between them intact and sometimes I want to replace the whole content within {USR} and {/USR} including both the opening and closing {USR} tags leaving other string contents untouched.

I tried many string functions but it just made my coding lengthy.

Comment: What you mean by 'sometimes'? It's going to be a manual call for replacement or your code must know when to replace?

Comment: I want to alter the string conditions using my way,if the request is only for username then i want to strike out the {PWD}{/PWD} part..Like That @DimasPante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$replacement = '$0';
if ($remove_tag_only) {
    $replacement = '$1';
} else if ($remove_all) {
    $replacement = '';
}
$string = preg_replace('~\{USR\}(.+?)\{/USR\}~s', $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Thanx for answering .But i want ,if the request is for username only then i want to remove {USR} & {/USR} but not the contents between them .As well as completely removal of "{PWD}Thank You For Connecting With "Company".Please Click on the below Link to Resest Yor Password.{/PWD}" line and vice versa.So please elaborate with the code @JE SUIS CHARLIE

Comment: @Chinmayapanigrahi: Sorry, I don't get you. Please edit your question and add the expected result.